# char (C++) manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, c++, character-encoding, char

I am trying to rewrite old code written in C++ to C# - code does binary manipulation with chars, but I recieve different results (probably I do some bad manipulation because of Unicode in C#).

I need to rewrite this C++ code to C#:

```
myChar = 'K' ^ 128;
```

Result of this code in C++ is **-53 ('Ë')** in C++'s data type char.

Same operation in C# results in **203 (again 'Ë')** in C#'s data type *char*.

So char is ok, but I need same byte value as in C++ (because I do math operation with that). Can you recommend way, how to safe convert C# char to equivalent C++ byte values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single byte two's complement representation 203 is an unsigned interpretation of of -53.

If you would like to use an equivalent representation of C++ signed char, the type should be `sbyte`:

```
sbyte myChar = (sbyte)('K' ^ 128);
```

Note that C++ standard leaves it up to the implementation to decide whether a `char` is signed or unsigned, which means that some standard-compliant C++ will print 203 for `myChar`, not -58, without any change to your code.